# How share a variable between two files in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, share

Using Node.js, if I write `app.js` as:

```
  var commons = {
    title: 'myTitle',
    description: 'MyDesc',
    menu: {
      home: {
        label: 'Home',
        url: '/',
      },
      contacts: {
        label: 'Contacts',
        url: '/contacts'
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(commons);
```

I've this output...

```
  {
    title: 'myTitle',
    description: 'MyDesc',
    menu: {
      home: {
        label : 'Home',
        url: '/'
      },
      contacts: {
        label: 'Contacts',
        url: '/contacts'
      }
    }
  }
```

...and it works fine.
But, if I would load a variable in `app.js` from another file (in the same path)...

`commons.js`:

```
exports.commons = {
    title: 'myTitle',
    description: 'MyDesc',
    menu: {
      home: {
        label: 'Home',
        url: '/',
      },
      contacts: {
        label: 'Contacts',
        url: '/contacts'
      }
    }
  }
```

`app.js`:

```
var commons = require('./commons');      
console.log(commons);
```

I've as output:

```
commons: {
        {
        title: 'myTitle',
        description: 'MyDesc',
        menu: {
            home: [Object],
            contacts: [Object]
        }
    }
 }
```

Why is this happening? How can I pass the variable across the two files correctly?

Comment: If you mean the `[Object]` thing, that's `console.log`'s ability to prevent spamming the console if an object is nested too much. `commons.menu.home.label` should work fine. I don't know why it shows `commons: { {` though - are you sure it shows `{ {` right after each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a module, `exports` is an object with all the things that are exported when the module is required somewhere else. So by setting `exports.commons = { ...` you are basically setting the `commons` property of the `exports` object. This means that you nested your actual object in another object for the export.

In your other module, you import then the whole `exports` object using `commons = require('./commons')`. So your actual `commons` object that you set is at `commons.commons`.

If you don’t want to nest the data in another object, you can just set the `exports` object directly, using `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = {
    title: 'myTitle',
    description: 'MyDesc',
    ....
}
```

Then the import works as you expect it to.

The `[Object]` in the output is, as pimvdb said, just something `console.log` does to not go too deep in the hierarchy. The data is still there, and you will probably see the contents just fine when you remove the first level as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

It's the depth to which the `console.log` goes. Adding one more level to the `commons` object gives the same response.

```
var commons = {
title: 'myTitle',
description: 'MyDesc',
menu: {
  home: {
    mine: {
      label: 'Home',
      url: '/',
    }
  },
  contacts: {
    label: 'Contacts',
    url: '/contacts'
  }
}
}
console.log(commons);
```

gives this response:

```
{ title: 'myTitle',
  description: 'MyDesc',
  menu:
   { home: { mine: [Object] },
     contacts: { label: 'Contacts', url: '/contacts' } } }
```

See this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs-dev/NmQVT3R_4cI